# What is "ClassName" used for in Worklight authenticationConfig?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

What is ClassName used for in the following?

```
  <realms>
<realm name="CustomDeviceProvisioningRealm" loginModule="CustomDeviceProvisioningLoginModule">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DeviceAutoProvisioningAuthenticator</className>
    <parameter name="validate-csr-function" value="ProvisioningAdapter.validateCSR" />
</realm>
```

Can I put more than on className in the same realm?
How can I merge an realm used for authentication with the realm used for Device provisioning?

For example: merging the one at the top with this one:

```
 <realm loginModule="BankingLoginModule" name="MobileBankingRealm">
        <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-function" value="AuthenticationAdapter.onAuthRequired" />
        <parameter name="logout-function" value="AuthenticationAdapter.onLogout" />
  </realm>
```

and how will this reflect on the Mobile Security test?

Answer (score 2):

The `classname` element designates which Java class implements the authenticator and/or login module.
There cannot be more than 1 per realm/login module.

The mentioned class names in your question are the default ones provided by Worklight.
These are public classes that can be extended, which may be what you're looking for, instead of "merging".

You can also create your own that implement `WorklightAuthenticator` and `WorklightLoginModule` interfaces.